# Turing's method to compute zeta function

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, riemann-zeta

I am trying to learn about Turing's method to perform calculations involving zeta function. I would like to learn the details of this method but the only references I found are his 1943 and 1953 papers on "The Turing Digital archive" but a lot of the details are left to the reader.

Are there any other books/literature  where I can find a detailed introduction of Turing's methods for zeta function?

Comment: Some details are in [Edwards' book (page 172-175)](https://books.google.com/books?id=ruVmGFPwNhQC&pg=PA172) (possibly not accessible sorry...)

Comment: Edwards' book exists in an inexpensive Dover reprint...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turing's 1952 paper ["Some calculations of the Riemann zeta-function"](https://books.google.com/books?hl=fr&lr=&id=C9WQbm4ovFoC&pg=PA265) is presented by Cooper and van Leeuwen in their book "Alan Turing - His Work and Impact" with quite some details.

Some additional references :

- Edwards' ["Riemann's Zeta function" book](https://books.google.com/books?id=ruVmGFPwNhQC&pg=PA172) (page $172-175$ possibly inaccessible...)
- Hejhal and Odlyzko (2011) ["Alan Turing and the Riemann Zeta Function"](http://www.dtc.umn.edu/~odlyzko/doc/turing.zeta.pdf)
- Trudgian's papers ["Improvements to Turing's Method I"](https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.1885) and [II](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.3416).

Answer (score 0):

I found the explanation in Section 3.2 of http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Miscellaneous/zetazeros1e13-1e24.pdf quite helpful.

Also p172-175 of Riemann’s Zeta Function (H.M. Edwards) as stated by other user.